# from interface{} how to find if the underlying value type OR the pointer to underlying Value Type implements an interface

Tags: go

Here is the specific problem I am hitting.

```
type MyInterface interface {
    MyMethod() error
}

type Request struct {
    Attr1    string
    Attr2    string
    Attr3    string
}

func (r *Request) MyMethod() error {
    return nil
}

func main() {
  req1 := Request{}
  someDecoratorMethod(req1)
  req2 := &Request{}
  someDecoratorMethod(req2)
}

func someDecoratorMethod(req interface{}) error {
    // here if req represents *Request I can easily find that it implements MyInterface

    //But if req represents Request, how can I find out that its pointer type *Request still implements MyInterface and that I can call MyMethod() on it?
}
```

I am guessing there is a possibility of doing this by reflection, but I am looking to see if there is a more performant and better way of achieving this.

Also from the fact that `go` doesn't let us define same method on value type if its already defined on pointer type, as well as pointer methods are transparently callable on value types, I think language should have an easy way to detect this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Request` does not implement `MyInterface`, only `*Request` does. Therefore it is not possible to check via the interface if there is a method called `MyMethod` on `Request`.

And strictly speaking there is no method `MyMethod` on `Request`. It is attached to `*Request`, not to `Request`. Go uses a little trick here when you call `MyMethod` on `Request`: it takes a pointer of `Request` under the hood to be able to call `MyMethod`.

Now to your question what options there are.

1. Change parameter type to `MyInterface`. And only pass `*Request`, not `Request`. Go is a typed language. Use it, don't fight it.
2. You can type cast to the struct type directly instead of using `MyInterface`.

```golang
func someDecoratorMethod(req interface{}) error {
    switch r := req.(type) {
    case Request:
        return r.MyMethod()
    case *Request:
        return r.MyMethod()
    }
    return errors.New("not implemented")
}
```